# Error: Missing Helper: "iff"

Tags: javascript, if-statement, handlebars.js

For some reason, I keep getting this error every time i try to use {{#iff}
Is this not rendering my page as handlebars? Did I use the {{#iff}} statement correctly?

My console prints this out:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

This is my handlebars(login.hbs):

```
<h1><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span> Login</h1>

{{#iff message.length '>' 0}}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{message}}</div>
{{/iff}}
```

This is my server.js

```
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');
const hbs = require('hbs');
var morgan       = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');


mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database

require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

// set up our express application
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // get information from html forms
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set('view engine', 'hbs'); // set up hbs for templating

// required for passport
app.use(session({
    secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch', // session secret
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session


require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport


app.listen(port);
console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```

In routes.js:

```
  app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
        res.render('login.hbs', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
    });
```

Comment: What is the `#iff` helper, and what are you expecting it to do? Did you mean `#if`?

Comment: I read here that you can't compare things with #iff https://code-maven.com/handlebars-conditionals

Comment: Anything in your console?

Comment: @MarkJ it looks like the code is on that page.

Comment: console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: What resource is it giving you a 500 on? Is it the handlebars file?

Comment: Yes it's the handlebars file

Comment: @MarkJ did you find any solution?